# How to Configure Nexus Sonatype docker image for inbound SSL?

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype

I installed NexusOSS using [docker-nexus](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/docker-nexus3/) on AWS, to use it as a docker private repository. After installation, I realized that docker private repo is enabled only if its inbound SSL is configured. Per [documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl-sect-ssl-direct.html) it can be done in two ways. I am trying to see how embedded jetty can be enabled for SSL.

Comment: See here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217542177-Using-Self-Signed-Certificates-with-Nexus-Repository-Manager-and-Docker-Daemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an nginx reverse proxy in front of nexus to get SSL connections to docker repo. I am running nexus and nginx in docker containers. I have a hosted and proxy docker repo and a group docker repo including the hosted and proxy one. The HTTP port for the group repo is 5000 (which is used to access all docker registry via nginx.conf)

Here is my approach with steps in README.md:
https://github.com/akailash/nginx_nexus